# Prove that $(0,1) =c\mathbb R$

Tags: cardinals

How do I prove this knowing that $f(x) = \tan(x\pi/2)$ is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0, \infty)$? We also have a bijection between $(-1,1)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean "given that we have a bijection $(0, 1)$ to $(0, \infty)$, why is the cardinality of $(0, 1)$ equal to that of $\mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry that the question was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Use what you have to define the bijection you need. You have a bijection:
$$
f\colon (0,1) \stackrel{\thicksim}\to (0,+\infty)
$$
Now you can define a bijection $g\colon (-1,1)\stackrel{\thicksim}\to \Bbb R$ by:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x)&\text{if $x>0$,} \\
0&\text{if $x=0$,} \\
-f(-x)&\text{if $x<0$.} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Finally, compose this with a bijection $h \colon (0,1)\stackrel{\thicksim}\to (-1,1)$ (for example, $x\mapsto 2x-1$) to get a bijection
$$
g\circ h\colon (0,1)\stackrel{\thicksim}\to \Bbb R.
$$